# what does "hitting the hour mark" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, conversation

what does "hitting the hour mark" mean in this conversation?

> a: How late is he?
> b: Hitting the hour mark. Hope there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression, to "hit the ______ mark", where there's some time unit in the blank means that's the amount of time that has passed.

In this example, *present continuous* is implied with *"-ing"* and the full sentence is: "It's hitting the hour mark." This means almost one hour has passed since he became late, or, more naturally, he's nearly an hour late.